# Cannot find MySQL Reference in Visial Studio 2008

Tags: mysql, vsto

Please, help me I want to add mysql reference in visial studio 2008 but I cannot find it. Can I download mysql reference and add it in to visial studio or not, or what should I do ???

Answer (score 0):

Download the MySQL connector for .NET, found [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

After installing you'll find it in the reference list.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download mysql component first
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/